# How to substitute a special character between words in R

Tags: regex, r, substitution

I have a string of characters.

```
str = c(".wow", "if.", "not.confident", "wonder", "have.difficulty", "shower")
```

I am trying to replace "." in between words with a whitespace. So it would look like this

```
".wow", "if.", "not confident", "wonder", "have difficulty", "shower"
```

First, I tried

```
gsub("[\\w.\\w]", " ", str)
[1] "  o "            "if"              "not confident"   " onder"         
[5] "have difficulty" "sho er "
```

It gave me the whitespace I want, but chopped off all the w's. Then, I tried

```
gsub("\\w\\.\\w", " ", str)
[1] ".wow"          "if"            "no onfident"   "wonder"       
[5] "hav ifficulty" "shower."
```

It kept the w's, but brought away other characters right before and after ".".

I cannot use this either

```
gsub("\\.", " ", str)
[1] " wow"             "if "              "not.confident"   "wonder"         
[5] "have.difficulty" "shower"
```

because it will take away "." not in between words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
gsub('(\\w)\\.(\\w)', '\\1 \\2', str)
#[1] ".wow"            "if."             "not confident"   "wonder"         
#[5] "have difficulty" "shower"
```

Or

```
gsub('(?<=[^.])[.](?=[^.])', ' ', str, perl=TRUE)
```

Or as @rawr suggested

```
gsub('\\b\\.\\b', ' ', str, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: It worked! Could you please humor me by explaining why I have to add the parentheses?

Comment: @wen It is already explained in hwnd's post.

Comment: @rawr Thanks, that is better.  I guess it won't work without the `perl=TRUE`

Comment: @rawr It gives me `gsub('\\b\\.\\b', ' ', str)#
[1] " wow"            "if "             "not confident"   "wonder"         
[5] "have difficulty" "shower" `

Answer (score 4):

Using [**capturing groups** and **back-references**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html):

```
sub('(\\w)\\.(\\w)', '\\1 \\2', str)
# [1] ".wow"            "if."             "not confident"   "wonder"         
# [5] "have difficulty" "shower"
```

A capturing group can be created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parenthesis `( ... )`. Backreferences recall what was matched by a capturing group.

A backreference is specified as (`\`); followed by a digit **indicating the number of the group**.

Using [**lookaround**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) assertions:

> Lookarounds are zero-width assertions. They don't "consume" any characters on the string.

```
sub('(?<=\\w)\\.(?=\\w)', ' ', str, perl = TRUE)
```