# Positive lookahead in R

Tags: regex, r

Novice on regular expressions here ...

Assume the following names:

```
names <- c("Jackson, Michael", "Lennon, John", "Obama, Barack")
```

I want to split the names, as to retain all the characters up to and including the first letter of the first name.  Thus, the results would look this:

```
Jackson, M
Lennon, J
Obama, B
```

I know this is a simple solution, but I am stuck on specifying what seems to be a reasonable solution -- that is, a positive lookahead regex.  I am specifying a match based on the comma, the space, and the first letter in caps. This is what I have but obviously it is wrong:

```
names.reduced <- gsub("(?=\\,\\s[A-Z]).*", "", names)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`(?= ... )`](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) is a zero-width assertion which does not consume any characters on the string.

It only matches a position in the string. The point of zero-width is the validation to see if a regular expression can or cannot be matched looking ahead  from the current position, without adding to the overall match. In this case, using a lookahead assertion is not necessary at all.

You can do this using a capture group, backreferencing the group inside the replacement call.

```
sub('(.*[A-Z]).*', '\\1', names)
# [1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```

Or better yet, you can use negation to remove all except `A` to `Z` at the end of the string.

```
sub('[^A-Z]*$', '', names)
# [1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```

Comment: What does `\\1` mean?

Comment: @BrianP, take a look at another [**answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29476130/2206004) of mine. `\\1` is the backreference to what was matched by the capture group `( ... )`

Answer (score 3):

You can use a lookbehind instead of the lookahead assertion

```
sub('(?<=, [A-Z]).*$', '', names, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `regmatches` function also.

```
> names <- c("Jackson, Michael", "Lennon, John", "Obama, Barack")
> regmatches(names, regexpr(".*,\\s*[A-Z]", names))
[1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```

**OR**

```
> library(stringi)
> stri_extract(names, regex=".*,\\s*[A-Z]")
[1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```

**OR**

Just match all the chars upto the last uppercase letter.

```
> stri_extract(names, regex=".*[A-Z]")
[1] "Jackson, M" "Lennon, J"  "Obama, B"
```